# What Could I Do To Improve This Scene

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials, lighting, scene

I was Hoping to get some critisism

[image: The Scene]

Comment: Hello, the Blender StackExchange is mainly for people who are encountering technical issues or have specific questions on how to accomplish something. There are plenty of other communities such as blenderartists.org where you can get feedback on your renders :) Check out https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic to see what types of questions should be posted here